# Pi4 won't boot when BCM17 pulled high

Tags: gpio

I have a boot issue with a system consisting of

- Raspberry Pi 4 B+
- Raspbian 10 (buster)
- 7" capacitive touch display (the "official" one) and a
- custom shield that pulls BCM17 (pin 11) high, when external 12V present.

Everything works fine with BCM17 when the system has booted. I can read the pin and it reflects the status of my external 12V.

But when I first apply 12V and then the Pi supply voltage, the system won't boot.

Comment: `the system won't boot.` what happens instead? what happens without the "official" (why is it in quotes) touch display?

Comment: by "what happens instead" I mean, does the activity light flash? does anything at all appear on the display? etc etc

Comment: What happens instead: Red led constantly on, green led constantly off. Display shows nothing. No SSH access from outside.

When I disconnect both the FPC cable and the power jumper cables that came with the Display and power up, the behavior is the same. Seems not to be display-related.

Comment: Oh, so the green led doesn't even flicker at all. Do you need/have any overlays loaded for this "custom shield"?

Comment: Exactly. The shield only uses GPIOs und the I2C. I activated the latter using raspi-config. The only line starting with dtoverlay in '/boot/config.txt' appears to be DRM related:

dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I was drawing too much current from the pin. Apparently this led to the startup issue.